# Pedometer with notifications in background iOS

Tags: ios, background-process

I want to do application that used steps counter (using M7) and i want to create the push notifications when user reached some steps. 
e.g. when user reached 500 steps, the app send a notification like "Hey, you're great!"
Well, is it possible in background mode? And how?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! (:

Please take a moment to overview [this tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this short article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Generally, questions should not be broad or general, and you should present your question along with things you have tried and failed and/or stuff you have figured out.

Since your question is fairly broad, my answer will be broad as well.
To access a pedometer with the built in chip on the iPhone you should use the `CoreMotion` framework, specifically the `CMMotionActivityManager(..)` by using it's 2 main methods: `startActivityUpdatesToQueue` and `queryActivityStartingFromDate(..)`. More info is available on the [iOS Dev Library Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/).

Sending a notification based on a local event is done using `UILocalNotification`, see [here on how to use it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/).

Good luck!